# What does "it" stand for?

Tags: pronouns, cleft-constructions

> The faeces contain nitrogen and **it** is that which fertilises the desert soil.

[source: A collection of a bunch of sentences](https://sentencedict.com/desert%20soil.html)

What does "it" stand for?

I'm considering two possibilities:

1, "it" refers to nitrogen. And "that which" can be replaced by "what".

2, "it is....which..." work together to make the cleft sentence construction.

Comment: (I'd say ***it*** is unquestionably a "dummy" in the cited context, where arguably ***that*** more explicitly refers to the "actual" noun ***nitrogen***.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It" does not technically refer to either the nitrogen or the faeces, but acts as a placeholder until "that which fertilises the desert soil" is identified. The word "*that*" then refers to the *nitrogen*:

> The faeces contain nitrogen and it is **that** which fertilises the desert soil.

It is the answer to the question "What is that which fertilises the desert soil?".

Comment: So it has the same meaning as ".... and it is **nitrogen that** fertilises the desert soil.", right?

Comment: @Robbyzhu Yes, nitrogen is (apparently) the thing in faeces that fertilises soil.